# Get Property by String Force Uppercase?

Tags: c#

I am using the C# `GetProperty`method using reflection.

> obj.GetType().GetProperty("columnName")

However I cannot guarantee the exact casing of the column name as it is being based in from an external source.  It maybe `ColumnName` or `columnname`

I was thinking if I could just force the string column name to uppercase, but how would I then deal with the Property on the object itself?  The getProperty method looks like it needs to be the EXACT casing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use

```
var prop = GetProperty("columnname",
                       BindingFlags.Instance | 
                       BindingFlags.Public | 
                       BindingFlags.IgnoreCase);
```

Note that you'll still need the `Instance` and `Public` bit (assuming that this *is* a public instance property) as otherwise it won't find anything.

Answer (score 6):

You can ignore the case when looking up the property.

```
GetProperty(fieldname, BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var yourprop = from x in obj.GetType().GetProperties()
               where x.Name.ToUpper() == "a column name".ToUpper()
               select x;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always combine reflection with some Linq magic, like this:

```
var property = typeof (MyType).GetProperties()
   .Where(p => p.Name.Equals("MyProperty", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
```